Get function's caller Bundle ID in Swift
I need to know a function's caller Bundle ID. Tried Thread.callStackSymbols but got 'B' instead of 'com.foo.B'
Scenario:
The project
import B
class P {
    private func callBFramework() {
        B.callAFramework()
    }
}

Framework B
import A
public class B {
    public static func callAFramework() {
        A.printBundleIDs()
    }
}

Framework A
public class A {
    public static func printBundleIDs() {
        let libraryBundleID = Bundle(for: self).bundleIdentifier 
                              ?? "Unknown Library Bundle ID"
        
        let appBundleID = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "Unknown App Bundle ID"

        
        // Here I need the caller's Bundle ID, couldn't get it from Thread.
        let callersBundleID = ...
        
        print("Library Bundle ID: \(libraryBundleID)")  // <- com.foo.A (A Framework)
        print("App Bundle ID: \(appBundleID)")          // <- com.foo.P (P Project)
        print("Caller's Bundle ID: \(callersBundleID)") // <- com.foo.B (B Framework)
    }

}

Why I need this
I have a logs library, that library will be consumed by other libraries and a project, in the project the client should be able to filter the logs dynamically based on who wrote them, I'm using the Bundle ID for that. To provide the Bundle ID as a parameter is not an  option.

@JoakimDanielson There is only one log instance provided by the project, the libraries wont create any instances so the Bundle ID cannot be provided at the instantiation, to provide it in each of the log calls is not very usable and not something I want to do for my library that's why I said that to provide it as parameter is not an option.

Can you require the caller of printBundleIDs to declare a class with a certain name? Then this can be done with some macro magic.

@Sweeper no, this is for a logs library pretty much most classes of the project and libraries will log something so no, cannot prefix or suffix everything...

I don't mean prefix/suffix everything. If the caller can just declare a class called e.g. BundleIDHelper, then a macro can expand to Bundle(for: BundleIDHelper.self) and get the ID.

@Sweeper no, this is for a KMP library, the classes use property delegation to be able to share log tags and the log instance is already provided through DI, this is already working and done in several Android apps, and JVM projects and I'm just migrating the log library to KMP, so I only need an iOS reflection way to get the Bundle ID of the function's caller nothing else.

Hold on a sec, does that mean the caller of printBundleIDs might not even be Swift code? I've found a way to use the Objective-C runtime to dynamically create a class so the caller doesn't need to declare an extra one, but if the caller is Kotlin I don't know how macros would port over to there.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
